# What languages provide SDKs for interacting with Genesys services?

Tags: python, pbx, genesys, pabx

Genesys is a contact center platform that provides software for working with both hard and soft PBXs. There are also a number of ancillary services they provide to support the wider contact center business.

I'm aware of the .NET and Java SDKs that Genesys supply on a first hand basis. Is there SDK support for any other languages and, specifically, is there an official Python library for interacting with their services?

Alternatively, are there any 3rd party libraries that are designed to interact with Genesys services for Python?

Comment: This is not "off topic" for the reasons mentioned because it's not asking for an opinion on "which is best". It's asking if such a library exists **at all**, and is therefore not open to opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are providing a C library, you can use ctypes to interact with it.

Comment: That's what I had planned to do if there was nothing already available. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, one could use ironpython (http://ironpython.net/) with the .net libraries from genesys.

FWIW, I use the java libs with jython.

I was kind of expecting the scripts to be interchangeable (ie. between jython
and ironpython) but unfortunately, the API differs in parts.
ie. the parameters to some of the functions are different or in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to interact with exacly? The GIS provides soap calls for a lot of functions.

Comment: GIS doesn't provide enough. Jython and the Java Platform SDK does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is neither a native C nor a Python library. Best bet is to use GIS as suggested.